# Excel - Find last same value in Column X and add Column Y to current cell

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that includes (3) different sources of information, where the source is determined in ColumnA, MoneyOut = ColumnB, MoneyIn = ColumnC, and SourceTotal = ColumnD.

When working with a current row, how can I find the last row in which ColumnA = CurrentRowColumnA[Value], and sum(PrevColumnB[Value]+PrevColumnC[Value]) to CurrentRowColumnD[Value].

Ex:

```
A1 = Source1
B1 = 200
C1 = 200
D1 = 400

A2 = Source2
B2 = 300
C2 = 200
D2 = 500

A3 = Source1
B3 = 200
C3 = 600
D3 = 1200 (D1 + sum(B3+C3))
```

How can I write a function to do this continuous addition without having to do a different sumifs for each row?

I've tried:
Assuming I'm on D4...

```
=SUM(IF(A:A=$A4, B4+C4))+IF($A3=$A4, D3)
```

Which will work for the first few, but once there is another source, this formula doesn't work.

Should I be using an OFFSET() function?

Comment: Please show what formula or code you've already tried.

Comment: Add it to the question, not in a comment.  Please read the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Whoops, apologies. First time on here. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: So, you're not using a `SUMIFS`?  Your question specifically mentions it.

Comment: Originally used SUMIFS to find the column value and then sum the MoneyIN+MoneyOUT columns, but it wouldn't allow for checking of multiple sources -- only one. As a result, I was going to nest a ton of IF() statements together to account for the multiple sources, but now I'm just overly confused as to which route to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula:

`=SUMIF($A$1:$A1,$A1,$B$1:$B1)+SUMIF($A$1:$A1,$A1,$C$1:$C1)`

Use this in your example sheet to get the result you want.

Comment: Please mark it as correct if it helped you to inform future visitors to the site.